# In Spring Boot, how to pass a model variable to service layer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, service, model

I want to use model variable in service layer,how can I do that?

Comment: I guess that we need a lot more context here. Which model? Available via REST API? Please be more detailed in your question. Thanks.

Comment: be more specific what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.